# Number of operations of tf.contrib.layers.separable_conv2d

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm

I'm reading the paper [Mobile Video Object Detection with Temporally-Aware Feature Maps](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.06368?context=cs) from CVPR2018, as well as the released code: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/lstm_object_detection.

Now, I have a problem with **equation (4)** in the paper:the cost of bottle-neck lstm is DK^2 * (M+N) * DF^2 + (M+N) * N * DF^2 +**4(DK^2 * N * DN^2 + N^2 * DF^2)**.

When I read into the source code [lstm/lstm_cells.py(118)](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/lstm_object_detection/lstm/lstm_cells.py#L118-L137) , I see that two consecutive tf.contrib.layers.seperable_conv2d are used to form the bottlenek-lstm described in the paper.

I have no question with the first two terms, however, for the *third* term, I think it should be (DK^2 * N * D2 + **4 * N^2 * DF^2)**. That is, the coefficient 4 should be applied to the latter inside the third term only, since tf.contrib.layers.separable_conv2d is consist of depthwise conv and pointwise conv, and **depthwise conv have nothing to do with output channels.**

Do I miss something? Or is it written incorrectly in the paper?

For the calculation of separable convolution, I follows [MobileNet paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.04861) equation (5).

Selected codes for bottleneck-lstm computation:

```
bottleneck = tf.contrib.layers.separable_conv2d(
         tf.concat([inputs, h], 3),
         self._num_units,
         self._filter_size,
         depth_multiplier=1,
         activation_fn=self._activation,
         normalizer_fn=None,
         scope='bottleneck')

if self._viz_gates:
       slim.summaries.add_histogram_summary(bottleneck, 'bottleneck')

concat = tf.contrib.layers.separable_conv2d(
         bottleneck,
         4 * self._num_units,
         self._filter_size,
         depth_multiplier=1,
         activation_fn=None,
         normalizer_fn=None,
         scope='gates')
```

For consistency, let

```
self._filter_size=[Dk,Dk]
self._num_units = N
inputs shape is [batch, DF, DF, M]
h shape is [batch, DF, DF, N]
```